# Адаптивный дизайн. Растянутые фото. Как поступить?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

Делаю адаптивный дизайн. Мне нужно растягивать фото на всю ширину экрана. Однако при таком подходе качество фотографии, с увеличением размера экрана сильно падает. Например, при ширине в `2000px` фото будет просто отвратным!

Что делать в таких ситуациях?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет свойство max-width.

Пример:

```
img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;

}
```

Картинка будет резиновой, до тех пор, пока размер по ширине не достигнет 1024 пикселей.

Comment: ну это я понял. А если экран 2000px. Тогда фотка наполовину экрана будет, а блоки 100%?

Answer (score 0):

[@navi1893](/users/4969/navi1893), использование jquery вы видите возможным на сайте?

Тогда вот простой плагин, который масштабирует изображение правильно:

1) **http://www.ollicle.com/projects/jquery/imagefit/eg/** (для картинок в img, будут подстраиваться размером под тот блок, в котором они находятся)

2) **http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/** (для фоновой картинки сайта)